# wp-ecommerce with multisite - not showing images

Tags: .htaccess, e-commerce, wordpress

Im using [wp_ecommerce](http://getshopped.org/) on a multisite (subfolder) site

The problem is that the plugin requests the images from:

http://mysite/blogname/files/wpsc/category_images/cat_1.png

while the images are stored on

http://mysite/blogname/wp-content/blogs.dir/16/files/wpsc/category_images/cat_1.png

So im getting broken images.

now im guessing that my htaccess should do this work for me .. so here is what is on there
So either my htaccess is wrong or something else should be configured ?

thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]


# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed that,

it turned out that the core WordPress file ms-files was not executable , 
meaning it had permissions set to 644 instead of 755

stetted up the appropriate permissions and it is working like a charm :-)